# Counting all contiguous sub-arrays given sum zero

Tags: algorithm

Given array of random numbers(positive, and negative) with length n, I want number contiguous sub-arrays which sum equals zero.

**Example:** 
Given I have array `a={1, -1 ,2 , -2, 6, -6}`, output will be `6` because sub-arrays are as the following:

```
1 -1 & 2 -2 & 6 -6 & 1 -1 2 -2 & 2 -2 6 -6 & 1 -1 2 -2 6 -6
```

I know brute force solution O(n^2), I want any another solution O(n), or O(n log n) ?

Comment: i dnt think `contiguous sub-arrays sum` problem has a `O(n), or O(n log n)` solution..

Comment: Since the total number of possible sub-arrays is O(n^2), I doubt you'll come up with a general algorithm better than that. If you do, it would have to be an approach that does not merely enumerate the sub-arrays.  Consider this difficult case: {6,0,0,...0,0,-6}.

Comment: Consider { 0, 0, ... 0, 0 }, now everything sums to zero and you have to output quadratically many things.

Comment: FYI: I think that @DavidEisenstat proved me wrong, below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let the array be a1, ..., an. Let s0, ..., sn be the prefix sums defined by sj = a1 + ... + aj (and s0 = 0). The sum of the subarray from i to j inclusive is sj - si-1. For an O(n)/O(n log n)-time algorithm, using a map, count the number of occurrences of each number among the prefix sums. Sum k choose 2 for k in the values of this map.

For example, if we have your array

```
1 -1 2 -2 6 -6
```

then the prefix sums are

```
0 1 0 2 0 6 0
```

and the counts are

```
0: 4
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1
```

and the output is 4 choose 2 + 1 choose 2 + 1 choose 2 + 1 choose 2 = 6 (where k choose 2 = k(k-1)/2).

In Python:

```py
def countsumzero(lst):
    prefixsums = [0]
    for x in lst:
        prefixsums.append(prefixsums[-1] + x)
    freq = {}
    for y in prefixsums:
        if y in freq:
            freq[y] += 1
        else:
            freq[y] = 1
    return sum(v*(v-1) // 2 for v in freq.values())
```

Comment: +1: Wow, nice! I didn't think there was a way around enumerating them all, but this sure seems to work.

Comment: I can't understand what's the next step after get prefix sums ?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I did not understand the reason behind sum(v*(v-1) // 2 for v in freq.values())

Comment: All is ok.But what is the last line "and the output is 4 choose 2 + 1 choose 2 + 1 choose 2 + 1 choose 2 = 6 (where k choose 2 = k(k-1)/2)." mean. This is not clear.