# Find the number of pairs in an array between which sum of elements is equal to 0

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Recently I encountered a question which says that we need to find the number of pairs in an array between(inclusive of both ends) which sum of elements is equal to 0. 
For eg : `int[] arr = {1,-2,3,0,-2,2}`. Then the pairs between which sum of elements is 0 are (3,5), (4,5), (0,4). So the ans = 3. Is there any way we can solve this in O(n) .

Comment: Use a hashmap..

Comment: Ok , that was quick . But how ?. I recently started with some practise of ds/algo. Your help will really be appreciated with some pseudo code :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all pairs of integers within an array which sum to a specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494130/find-all-pairs-of-integers-within-an-array-which-sum-to-a-specified-value)

Comment: @Anshul Store all elements in map. Check if map has -A[i] value

Comment: Counting pairs can be O(n) however accumulating them cannot be O(n)

Comment: Your question is a little hard to parse.  I think you want to count all the contiguous subarrays with zero sum, but commenters seem to think you want to count all pairs with zero sum.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, yes you are right , I want to find all contiguous subarrays with 0 sum

Comment: @Anshul Then see if this question helps: [Counting all contiguous sub-arrays given sum zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532723/counting-all-contiguous-sub-arrays-given-sum-zero)

Answer (score 0):

The trick you need for this one is to build an array of cumulative sums, so that `sums[i] = sum of all arr[0] through arr[i]`.

Of course, if `sums[i] == 0`, then `(0,i)` is one of the pairs you're looking for, and you should count it.

For all the other ones, note that if the sum of `arr[i] though arr[j]` is zero, then `sums[i-1] == sums[j]`.

So you just need to know how many matching pairs of values there are in `sums`.

Make a hash map from value->number that gives the frequency of each value in `sums`.  Then, for each count `m` that's at least 2, you have `m*(m-1)/2` pairs.