# Find number of subarrays with sum zero in O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

This is sub-problem of a general 2-D problem in which I am trying to solve by reducing to above 1-D problem.
The above problem can be easily solved using brute force in O(n^2) time. The below solution is trying to do in O(n)time.
The approach is as follows:

```
      Goal : sum(i,j)==0
      sum(i,j) = sum(0,j) - sum(0,i);
      sum(i,j) = 0 => sum(0,j) == sum(0,i)
```

The algorithm calculates cumulative sum and uses hashmap (unordered_map in c++) to find number of equal sums.This is by using

```
      [ preSum(sum)*(presum(sum)-1) ]/2;
```

The other edge case is when element is zero in array, count is incremented because the element will be a subarray too.
The below solution breaks at one case.I am not able to determine the case/edge case where the below code breaks.

```
      int findCount(vector<int> temp){
         int m = temp.size();
         unordered_map<int,int> preSum;
         int count = 0;
         int sum = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < m;i++){
            sum+=temp[i];
            if(temp[i]==0){
                count++;
            }else if(sum==0){
                count++;

            }
            if(preSum.find(sum)!=preSum.end()){
             preSum[sum]+=1;
            }else{

            preSum[sum] = 1;
            }
         }
       for(auto x : preSum){
            if(x.second > 1 )
                count+= (x.second * (x.second-1))/2;

       }
       return count;
     }
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532723/counting-all-contiguous-sub-arrays-given-sum-zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach:

```
  Goal : sum(i,j)==0
  sum(i,j) = sum(0,j) - sum(0,i);
  sum(i,j) = 0 => sum(0,j) == sum(0,i)
```

assumes that `i` and `j` are positions *between* elements.  These range from `0` to `length`, NOT from `0` to `length-1`.  With that interpretation, the above is exactly correct and requires no "edge cases".

Your code seems to assume that `i` and `j` are inclusive indexes of elements, which range from `0` to `length-1`.

In that case:

```
   sum(i,j) = sum(0,j) - sum(0,i-1)  //assume sum(0,-1) = 0
   sum(i,j) = 0 => sum(0,j) = sum(0,i-1)  if i>0 or
                   sum(0,j) = 0 if i=0
```

This requires separate counting of the situations where `i=0`

In no case do you need special handling of `0` elements.

Comment: Understood. I couldn't articulate my thought process why I even went for special handling.

Answer (score 1):

*Approach*:

As common approach with problems involving subarrays, you should use **prefix sums** to add each subarray.

Let `p` contain our **prefix sums**, and let `nums` be the given array.

Let `p[i+1] = nums[0] + nums[1] + ... + nums[i]` (length of `p` = length of `nums` + 1).

Then, each subarray can be written as `p[i-1] - p[i]`.  Thus, we can have `p[i-1] - p[i] == 0`, or not.

*Algorithm*:

Disclaimer: 0s are indeed subarrays. However, if you do not want to count them, you should remove them from the input array before doing what follows. I did not remove the 0s.

Create the array `p` containing **prefix sums** and count all the `p[i] == 0`.

However, bear in mind that count `c` will be done considering that there are `c*num` values `p[i] == 0`. Then, there are `sum(c*(c-1)/2)` possible subarrays.

My solution is in Python 3.6+ and can be used as blueprint for yours.

```py
'''
Time Complexity: O(N), where N is the length of nums
Space Complexity: O(N)
'''
from collections import Counter

def zeroSumSub(nums):
    if not nums:
      return -1

    p = [0]
    for num in nums:
        p.append(p[-1] + num)

    count = Counter(p)
    return sum(v*(v-1)//2 for v in count.values())
```

If you are not comfortable with Python:

`p[-1]` is like `p[len(nums)-1]` (thus, returns the last element of array).

`Counter` is an unordered collection where elements are stored as `dict` keys (**prefix sums**) and their count as `dict` value (count `c`). In a nutshell, it counts hash-table objects.

`//` is integer division.

Answer (score 0):

```
void solve()
{
    int ans = 0, sum = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    map<int, int> mp;
    mp[0] = 1;
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sum += a[i];
        ans += mp[sum];
        mp[sum]++;
    }
    cout<<ans;}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class SubArrSumZero {

```
public int SubArr(int arr[],int n)
{
     int sum;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
         sum=0;
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
             sum=arr[i]+arr[j];
            
        }
        if(sum==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            break;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No");
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int  sum;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements:");
    int n,i;
    n=sc.nextInt();
    int arr[]=new int[100];
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Array is:");
     for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(" "+arr[i]);
    }
     SubArrSumZero sz=new SubArrSumZero();
     sz.SubArr(arr, n);
}
```

}

Comment: please correct this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).